# Find object with max date in a list where date property is a String

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, comparator, localdate

Say I have an object:

```
public class MyObject {
     private LocalDate date;
}
```

In a list of these objects it's then quite easy to find the object with the newest date:

```
MyObject newest = Collections.max(myObjectList, Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getDate));
```

Is there a similarly concise way to find the object with the newest date when the date is a String instead? I need to convert the dates to LocalDates first, but I can't do something like this:

```
MyObject newest = Collections.max(myObjectList, Comparator.comparing(LocalDate.parse(MyObject::getDate)));
```

Comment: Depends on the date format. If it's `yyyyMMdd`a simple lexicographic sort is enought

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `MyObject::getDate` returns a format that is acceptable for `LocalDate.parse`, you are nearly correct. You just need to write a lambda expression:

```
Comparator.comparing(o -> LocalDate.parse(o.getDate()))
```

`comparing` takes a `Function<MyObject, T>`. You are supposed to give it a method that takes a `MyObject` and returns something (that extends `Comparable`) for it to compare.

Learn more about lambdas [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an utility method and then use it in functional style:

```
static <T> Function<T, LocalDate> parsingDate(Function<T, String> extractor){
    return t -> LocalDate.parse(extractor.apply()));
}

MyObject newest = max(myObjectList, comparing(parsingDate(MyObject::getDate)));
```